# How to log a single-board computer events?

Tags: hardware, debugging, assembly

I have a single-board computer, I want to knows whats going on when it boot up and start up because i never get access to its BIOS, can I log the events/activities happening on the board when it get started?

**EDIT 1**

the logging im trying to achieve is for instances, Java/C#/Python program we can have a system log to monitor whenever it get started, from initializing system components/classes/objects, to API/functions/Server started, we can have the entire program starting process knowing.

I want to achieve this kind of logging monitor to my single-board computer, is it possible? For example our computer, we know it boot up from BIOS, Operating System, our startup processes, but don't know the event what is actually going on, how much RAM space did operating system allocating when boot up? how CPU processing all these boot up procedures?

similar to these, can we have the logging? how to log the entire procedure?

**EDIT 2**

my question are also bring in a thought of how hardware engineer knowing their component works properly, after input/install firmware?

**EDIT 3**

What i want to achieve is similar to Android Device logcat, logging every events from system boot up

**EDIT 4**

I'm using Antminer L3_IO_Board_V1.2

Answer (score 1):

What's the make and model of the single board computer? Does it have a serial port? If so then you might be able to get POST messages over serial.

What OS are you running? With most flavors of Linux you can remove the quiet and splash entries in grub to show the boot time info, and you can also access that via the 'dmesg' command.  I think boot logging is possible in Windows, but I don't know right off hand how to enable it.

Comment: im using L3_IO_Board_V1.2, i dont know whether it has serial port because im very new to this kind of debugging, but your information is valuable, many thanks to your advice

Comment: Unfortunately I have no experience with those, but from what I can tell, it's either going to be running the Antminer proprietary software or maybe you've got a custom OS on it. If it's stock I'd recommend contacting Antminer to see if there's a way to enable diagnostic logging since it's only connectivity appears to be ethernet.  If it's a custom OS, then the person/people who built it should be able to either enable logging (via remote syslog or similar) or at least tell you whether or not it's even possible.  Best of luck!

Comment: well, thanks for your info :D you are being very helpful, anyway, i will try out your advising